# Traverse inside table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with multiple table rows inside it, each td has an input inside it, i'm trying to traverse inside the table row so i can set the value of an input through another input, it only works for the first table row, how can i make for all the rows in the table? and i have a button that appends a tr when i apped a new tr it doesn't set the value inside it, here is my code:

```js
$('.myFirstInput').closest('tr').find('.mySecondInput').val('1000');

$('button').click(function () {
    var tr = '<tr><td><input type="text" class="myFirstInput"</td>'+
             '<td><input type="text"></td>' +
             '<td><input type="text" class="mySecondInput"></td></tr>';
    $('tbody').append(tr); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="myFirstInput"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="mySecondInput"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><input type="text" class="myFirstInput"></td>
     <td><input type="text"></td>
     <td><input type="text" class="mySecondInput"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><input type="text" class="myFirstInput"></td>
     <td><input type="text"></td>
     <td><input type="text" class="mySecondInput"></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button>Append row</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're using IDs, which must be unique in HTML. Change them to classes instead and this should work as expected.

```js
function addVal() {
  var elems = $('.myFirstInput').closest('tr').find('.mySecondInput');
  $.each(elems, function(s, e) {
  if($(e).val() === '') {
      $(e).val('1000');
   }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$('button').click(function () {
   var tr = '<tr><td><input type="text" class="myFirstInput"</td>'+
'<td><input type="text"></td>' +
'<td><input type="text" class="mySecondInput"></td></tr>';
   $('tbody').append(tr);
      addVal();
  });
    
    addVal();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="myFirstInput"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="mySecondInput"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="myFirstInput"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="mySecondInput"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="myFirstInput"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="mySecondInput"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button>Append row</button>
```

Comment: Okay, in that case you need a method with your insert value functionality that can run on page load and also when you click your button. I updated the answer - this is a kind of cheaty way to do it but it should work for your use case.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using `id`'s. By definition, `id`'s should be unique. When your code runs, it only applies to the first item with that `id` that it finds. Simply changing your `id`'s to `class` should do the trick (for that part).

Secondly, it looks like you are creating rows dynamically (adding `tr`'s). run that same function whenever you insert new rows:

```js
$('.myFirstInput').closest('tr').find('.mySecondInput').val('1000');

$('button').click(function () {
    var tr = '<tr><td><input type="text" class="myFirstInput"</td>'+
'<td><input type="text"></td>' +
'<td><input type="text" class="mySecondInput"></td></tr>';
    $('tbody').append(tr);
    $('.myFirstInput').closest('tr').find('.mySecondInput').val('1000');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
<th>1</th>
<th>2</th>
<th>3</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" class="myFirstInput"></td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="mySecondInput"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" class="myFirstInput"></td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="mySecondInput"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" class="myFirstInput"></td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="mySecondInput"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<button>Append row</button>
```

Comment: But why not just hard-code the value in the new row that you create dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

It is not right to use multiple `id` with the same name in the same `document`. Use `class` instead like the following way:

```js
$('input.mySecondInput').each(function(i, el){
  $(el).val('1000');
});

$('button#btnAppendRow').click(function () {
  var tr = '<tr><td><input type="text" class="myFirstInput"</td>'+
  '<td><input type="text"></td>' +
  '<td><input type="text" class="mySecondInput"></td></tr>';
  $('tbody').append(tr);

  $('input.mySecondInput:last-child').val('1000');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="myFirstInput"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="mySecondInput"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="myFirstInput"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="mySecondInput"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="myFirstInput"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="mySecondInput"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="btnAppendRow">Append row</button>
```

Comment: @jessica, though late, I have updated my answer according to your updated question.....thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must give unique identifiers for each input element.  First row should have *myFirstInput1* and *mySecondInput1*.  Second row, *myFirstInput2* and *mySecondInput2*, and so on.  That way you'll be able to reference each input precisely.